# Bootstrap: inherited padding?

Tags: html, css

Where does navigation inherit/get left padding 40px?
Could someone explain this?

```
   <div id="nav" class="show-search">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="desktop" id="navigationbg">
        <ul id="navigation">
          <li class="active" ><a href="#">desktop</a></li>
          <li class="has_sub"><a href="#">TP</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">RA</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ST</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PT</a></li>
        </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Y</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        </ul>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPjrgJ

Answer (score 2):

`ul` has `padding-left` set by default. You can override this by doing:

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is set from `your browser's system style`

```
ul, menu, dir {
 -moz-padding-start: 40px; // here 
 display: block;
 list-style-type: disc;
}
```

In order to reset it, just set `padding-left:0;`

```
ol, ul {
 padding-left: 0;
}
```

*Get and learn how to use **[FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)** and thank me later!*